# MERN for e-commerce?

Tags: reactjs, e-commerce, single-page-application, mern, multi-page-application

I am trying to learn how to build an eCommerce store with 2000+ products. My first quest was to pick a stack. Most google results suggest that the MEAN / MERN stack is the best for eCommerce. So, i started learning MongoDB NodeJS ExpressJS as well as CSS HTML and JavaScript. Then, it was time to choose between Angular and React. The choice was easy, most courses and tutorials i came across were using React. Once i started learning React i was introduced to the concept of SPA. Then i started researching and found that MPAs are considered a better choice for eCommerce which got me really confused. If MPAs are better than SPAs for eCommerce, why the internet is filled with MEAN / MERN suggestions as well as eShop building courses? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here][1]I think `SPA` library or framework (React, Angular) is suitable for E-Commerce website. Because it has very fast page load once you have loaded a site. Page load = higher conversion. We see a conversion point increase of 0.4% to 1.5% on SPA than MPAs.

Also, it reduces frequent page reloading. There is big community support for SPA frameworks and libraries as well.

However, you have to figure out how to make it SEO friendly by using something like `NextJs` (https://nextjs.org/) or `Gastby` (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) for `SSR` (Server side rendering).